# Is there a way to export java functions to other packages within a library, but not to users of the library?

Tags: java, visibility

So, here's an example. I have a library in the package `HTTP`. I define sub-sections of the library in e.g. the package `HTTP.TCPProtocol`. Now I want to use TCPProtocol from the HTTP package, which means I have to make the TCPProtocol functionality public. At the same time, this functionality should not be exported to users of the library.

How do I do this? I don't want to shove my whole library into one package, as I feel the separate sub-packages really make the code more structured and navigation easier in eclipse. But browsing around, I couldn't find a method to expose functions within my project, but not export them outside my project.

EDIT: In light of me being able to come up with a better example, I'm updating the OP.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at [OSGi bundles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Bundles).

Comment: Thanks, it does look like a solution, but OSGi seems a little heavy-weight for merely distributing a shared library .jar to developers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the caller's class to lock out all unwanted callers. The caller's class can be obtained from the stacktrace. In the example below, only instances of Bar will trigger the system.out.println, all all other will get an exception. You can even do package-level checks this way. Make sure that all allowed caller classes methods are not public, or they can call the doSomething method indirectly. You can even do deeper checks, by inspecting the stacktrace further.

Be aware though, that a skilled develper can circumvent anything you try do do in this matter. No solution is really "secure".

```
package one.two;

import one.Bar;

public class Foo {

    public void doSomething() {

        StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
        StackTraceElement stackTraceElement = stackTrace[2];
        String className = stackTraceElement.getClassName();

        if (Bar.class.getName().equals(className)) {
            System.out.println("jay!");
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("not allowed");
        }

    }
}
```

---

```
package one;

import one.two.Foo;

public class Bar {

    void makeCall() {
        new Foo().doSomething();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Bar().makeCall();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

One simplistic approach is to whitelist your 'utility' methods so they take a caller instance of a certain type only.

```
package gameengine;

interface Whitelisted {} // marker
```

Then your method:

```
public void myMethod(Whitelisted caller, String arg)
```

And to invoke:

```
package gameengine.network;

class Foo implements Whitelisted {
...
Someclass.myMethod(this, "foo");
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. How will gameengine.network get a grip on Whitelisted, though? Doesn't the interface need to be public for that? :)

Comment: That's true. I didn't want to have a `myMethod` with a caller of every possible type that might want to call it but that's the only other approach that I can think of now.

Comment: Also this assumes that the whitelisted classes cannot be instantiated (like singletons).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your dependencies, the only real advice the community can give you is to refactor your code.  If something in your networking package needs to know about your game engine, it seems like you have a leaky abstraction.  Hard to say without seeing your code.

Comment: It's less that the abstraction is leaky, and more that I'm used to being able to layer my abstraction. I mean, to give you a very simple example.. What if I wanted to write an HTTP library, but not allow the user of my library to send just any kind of TCP messages? Having a separate TCP package makes sense from a conceptual segregation standpoint, but that'd instantly force me to make the(well abstracted) TCP functions visible to library users, even if I don't want them to be.